# Show CSS rules of an element with an id in a textarea when clicking on that element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created several shapes with CSS, each shape is contained in an element with an id, for example id="square". What I want is the following: If I click on the shape, I would like to display its CSS rules in a `textarea`.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div id="square" class="box"> parallelogram </div></li>
    <li><div id="parallelogram" class="box"> parallelogram </div></li>
    <li><div id="parallelogram2" class="box"> parallelogram2 </div></li>
</ul>
<textarea name="show" id="show" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

And my CSS:

```
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#parallelogram {
  width:100px;
  height:70px;
  background:blue;
  -webkit-transform:skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform:skew(20deg);
  -o-transform:skew(20deg);
  transform:skew(20deg);
}

#parallelogram2 {
  width:100px;
  height:70px;
  background:blue;
  -webkit-transform:skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform:skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform:skew(-20deg);
  transform:skew(-20deg);
}
```

And the jQuery code I currently have:

```
$(".box").click(function () {
  var id = $(this).parents().attr('id');
  var cssrules=document.styleSheets[0].rules["id"].style.cssText;
  $("#show").html("cssrules");
});
```

Also see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/q9v7f/). Here's [another one](http://jsfiddle.net/sGe9c/) with all my shapes.

Comment: Do you want to show the ID or the complete css code of that element?

Comment: Your code is horrible to read. Less whitespace helps! And why is `cssrules` a string if you want to show the contents of the variable? `$(this).parents().attr('id')` is also bad; it not only tries to read an attribute ending with a whitespace but `.parents()` also matches **all** parent elements....

Comment: @caizZZz: I edited the title and description a bit to make your goal a bit clearer. Please feel free to revert if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whitespace issues are actually preventing this from working at all - there is a difference between $("#show") and $("#show "), so you should really be more careful with this. I fixed the markup:

```
<body> 
  <div class="main"> 
    <ul> 
      <li><div id="square" class="box">parallelogram0</div></li> 
      <li><div id="parallelogram" class="box">parallelogram1</div></li> 
      <li><div id="parallelogram2" class="box">parallelogram2</div></li> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
  <textarea name="show" id="show " cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

To get your inline style sheet, you should iterate over `document.styleSheets` and grab the one that has an `href` attribute with value `null` - the other ones are external style sheets. Since all your elements are referenced by id and the corresponding CSS rules start with # we can get the rule corresponding to a shape by testing whether the `selectorText` attribute of a rule starts with "#":

```
for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (document.styleSheets[i].href === null)
        var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
}

$(".box").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;
    for (var i=0; i<rules.length; i++) {
        if (rules[i].selectorText.indexOf("#"+id) == 0) {
            var rule = rules[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    $("#show").val(rule.cssText);
});
```

You can access the style sheets only by index, they're held in an array. Finally, you have to set the value of the `textarea`, not its `html`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sGe9c/7/) is a jsfiddle illustrating it.

Comment: i test it ,but it dont work. this is the complated code http://jsfiddle.net/sGe9c/

Comment: That's because you didn't use what I wrote ;) Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sGe9c/7/).

Comment: if i use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" /> ,how to complate.??

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation,but i only 11 reputation

Comment: sorry,iam newer!! now that is OK

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If you are interested, have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for these kinds of details!

Answer (score 1):

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/fHvpL/

I did this by using the functions defined in this question - [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Then changing your jQuery code to -

```
$(".box").click(function(){

      var style = $.param(css($(this))).replace(/&/g,';\n');
      $("#show").val(style); 

  });
```

Comment: hah, if i click <div id="parallelogram" class="box"> .box ,only return the code #parallelogram    width:100px;
  height:70px;
  background:blue;
  -webkit-transform:skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform:skew(20deg);
  -o-transform:skew(20deg);
  transform:skew(20deg);